# web3.js encrypt and decrypt keystore v3 standard

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js

Im using the javascript version of [web3](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js) and want to import a private key from a [Web3 Secret Storage Definition](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Web3-Secret-Storage-Definition) file (old wiki: [Passphrase protected key store spec](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Passphrase-protected-key-store-spec)
). According to [the docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html) there is a decrypt and encrypt funtion:

```
keystoreJsonV3 = web3.eth.accounts.encrypt(privateKey, password);
privateKey = web3.eth.accounts.decrypt(keystoreJsonV3, password);
```

But I get an 'Uncaught TypeError: web3.eth.accounts.decrypt is not a function'. What is wrong? Is the docs wrong or is my web3.js the wrong version or something similar? How do I encrypt/decrypt keystore files.

I built my web3.js file from this source

```
git clone -b develop  https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js.git
```

Answer (score 0):

Those functions are not implemented yet. The functions you relate to are mostly described in the 1.0.0 version of web3 which has not been release yet.

Right now, web3.eth.accounts just retrieves an array of available accounts loaded from testrpc/ganache-cli/geth instance running on your machine.

Comment: try adding web3 in your package.json specifying the version you want :

in package.json : 

"web3": "^1.0.0-beta.26"

then do ```npm install``` 

This might work